# ¿Cómo usar MathJax en Cakephp 3?

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Hola nunca había usado el plugin MathJax pero esta vez me es necesario usarlo en mi proyecto, estoy usando Cakephp 3 ya instale MathJax en mi proyecto pero no tengo idea de como implementarlo, he leído en su pagina de algunos ejemplos trato de aplicarlo pero no logro interpretarlo para cake.

Comparto el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax TeX Test Page</title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://example.com/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$
</body>
</html>
```

Sabemos que en Cake los js se llaman de la siguiente forma:

```
echo $this->Html->script('verifica_internet');
```

Nose como implementar esto:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
    </script>
```

Comment: ¿Quieres llamar ese script en una vista en especial o directamente en el layout?

Comment: @KacosPro directamente en el layout

Comment: Puedes hacerlo directamente en el default.ctp como lo muestras en el ejemplo

Comment: @KacosPro lo llamo asi  <script async src="<?= $this->Url->build(ROOT.DS.'webroot'.DS.'MathJax'.DS.'MathJax.js'); ?>"></script>   en el default

Comment: ¿Cómo instalaste la librería?

Comment: @KacosPro la descargue y meti los  archivos en webroot

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera  en el layout puse el siguiente código:

```
<script async src="<?= $this->Url->build('/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'); ?>"></script> 
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
```

Yo estaba poniendo mal la ruta y gracias a @KacosPro que me hizo ver mi error